# Is it the right way to do that?

Tags: c#, oop

I`m wondering about how can i improve this code below, because i think there is a better way to do that, may be through properties?

```
class Note
{
    public readonly string receiver = "";
    public readonly string sender = "";
    public readonly string subject = "";
    public readonly string body = "";

    public Note(string sender, string receiver, string subject, string body)
    {
        if (receiver.Length > 0 && receiver.Length < 40)
            this.receiver = receiver;
        else
            this.receiver = "Anonymous";

        if (sender.Length > 0 && sender.Length < 40)
            this.sender = sender;
        else
            this.sender = "Anonymous";

        if (subject.Length > 0 && subject.Length < 40)
            this.subject = subject;
        else
            this.subject = "no subject";

        if (body.Length > 0 && body.Length < 40)
            this.body = body;
        else
            this.body = "no message";
    }
}
```

a lot of if statements in constuctor, i tried readonly properties and it was messy, i want to know how can i improve the code?

And if it would be done through properties, how can i prevent of using private variable within the class?

Comment: Questions about improving otherwise working code may be better suited for [codereview.se], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at least extract the method to handle the repeating logic:

```cs
class Note
{
    public readonly string receiver = "";
    public readonly string sender = "";
    public readonly string subject = "";
    public readonly string body = "";

    public Note(string sender, string receiver, string subject, string body)
    {
        this.receiver = GetOr(receiver, "Anonymous");
        this.sender = GetOr(sender, "Anonymous");
        this.subject = GetOr(subject, "no subject");
        this.body = GetOr(body, "no message");
    }

    private static string GetOr(string incoming, string defaultValue)
        => incoming.Length > 0 && incoming.Length < 40
            ? incoming
            : defaultValue;
```

Also I recommend to follow [C# coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), in this particular case - properties/fields names should be Pascal case (also you should consider using properties instead of fields):

```cs
class Note
{
    public string Receiver { get; }
    public string Sender { get; }
    public string Subject { get; }
    public string Body { get; }

    public Note(string sender, string receiver, string subject, string body)
    {
        Receiver = GetOr(receiver, "Anonymous");
        Sender = GetOr(sender, "Anonymous");
        Subject = GetOr(subject, "no subject");
        Body = GetOr(body, "no message");
    }

    private static string GetOr(string incoming, string defaultValue) 
         => incoming.Length is > 0 and < 40
            ? incoming
            : defaultValue;
}
```